# Php5.3 magic method __call and Memory

Tags: memory, call, php-5.3

I have a script with using a lot of Magic method __call.
The script have 15 000 iterance and the object is bigger. 
After every iterance the memory grows. I use unset or $val = null; but the memory continues to grow.

What can i do?

An Exemple :

```
$data = null;
foreach ($field['method']['actions'] as $action) {
    // si l'action ne concerne pas le name space principal
    if (!array_key_exists('get', $action)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (array_key_exists('begin', $action)) {
        $data .= $action['begin'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('action', $action)) {
        $obj = $notice->__call('get' . ucfirst($action['action']));
        $notice->clear();
        if (is_object($obj)) {
            $rsl = $obj->__call('get' . ucfirst($action['get']));
            $obj->clear();
            echo "\n" . 'get' . ucfirst($action['get']) . ' : '  . number_format(memory_get_usage());
            $data .= $rsl;
            unset($rsl);
        } else {
            $data .='';
        }
        $obj = null;
    } else {
        $data .= $notice->__call('get' . ucfirst($action['get']));
        $notice->clear();
        echo "\n" . 'get' . ucfirst($action['get']) . ' : '  . number_format(memory_get_usage());
    }
    if (array_key_exists('end', $action)) {
        $data .= $action['end'];
    }
}
//--
class Notice{
    //--

    protected $instanceObj = null;

    public function __call($name, $arguments = null) {
        $this->instanceObj = $this->$name($arguments);
        return $this->instanceObj;
    }

    public function clear(){
         $this->instanceObj = null;
     }

    //--
}
```

An exemple of log file :

```
getField : 24,446,752
getField : 24,447,352
getField : 24,447,720
getField : 24,448,096
getField : 24,483,320
getField : 24,483,336
getField : 24,483,728
...
getField : 25,267,936
...
getField : 35,596,712
...
```

You can see the memory never stop to brows.

Comment: If you believe you've found a memory leak in PHP, you can post a bug report and get a "thank you but this is not a bug" reply. That's how it usually goes with PHP bugs. Otherwise, if you can make a minimal example that still exhibits the memory leak and post it here, we might take a look if anything else is wrong with it.

Comment: My question is completed

Comment: Your code is insufficient to reproduce your problem. You're not invoking `Notice::__call()` as a magic method _at all_ (you're explicitly calling it, so nothing magical happens), you're calling other `Notice` methods inside the `__call()` method which are not defined in your example, and there is no input data (the `$field['method']['actions']` array) to run your code against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to sequence the script several execution. The problem is not PHP Symfony but generates too many objects. So I run the script Pacquet x. Otherwise it led to a saturation of memory.